# How to disable and Collapse a single header of the JQuery Accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 4 Headers in Accordians and I want to disable and Collapse the First header only out of all 4 headers as follows:

```
$("#ExpandCollapse").accordion({
         active: false,
         collapsible: true
  });
```

For Disabling I am using

```
$(".IncludeAnalysis").addClass("ui-state-disabled");
```

where .IncludeAnalysis is the class given to first header.I want to collapse and Disable it except others(Non Collapsible + Non Disabled)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you are asking to do is to have your first panel collapsed and disabled, and all three of your other panels open at once.  If so, you're misinterpreting what `collapsible` means, and misunderstanding the purpose of an accordion.

An accordion allows you to have multiple sets of content in a set of panels that overlap each other.  You can look at one of these panels at a time.  This allows you to have more content on the page than will fit on the screen at one time.  It's similar in purpose to a set of tabs.  You select one tab at a time, and have access to the content on that tab.  If you want access to different content, you select a different tab.  So, what you are asking to do is analogous to asking to have more than one tab selected at once in a tabbed display.  It doesn't work that way.  You only see one at a time, and the user clicks on the header of the panel they want to see.

The `collapsible` option allows you to have *no* panels open (i.e. active); by setting it to true you are saying is that you can collapse (i.e. close) the entire accordion.  Otherwise, one panel is always open.  By default, the first one is active/open on load. If you want to close it, you make a different panel active, typically by clicking on it.  As the doc says for `collapsible`:

> Whether all the sections can be closed at once. Allows collapsing the active section.

You have looked at the doc for the `active` option.  As you have done in your code, setting `collapsible` to true and `active` to false (which means that no panels are active) closes the entire accordion.  In other words, it makes none of the panels active.

You are disabling the first panel correctly.  Now I suggest that you open the second panel, and leave the others closed but enabled.  To do this, just set the `active` option to 1:

```
$("#ExpandCollapse").accordion({
     active: 1
});
```

You don't need to set `collapsible` unless you want to close all panels.

That's the closest you're going to come to what you want.  If you want all three panels to display, then you don't want to use an accordion.